# Absolute positioning issue with internal links

Tags: html, css

http://dev.epicwebdesign.ca/karen/2-4/a/#antartica

Absolutely positioning the continents, for some reason the links don't go to the proper place. Is this a shortfall of absolute positioning, or am I doing something stupid?

The anchors are around the headers as they should be.

Just realized it's going to the top of the image, not the headers underneath. Why?

Comment: Your code works exactly as expected. Passing a `hash` in the URL scrolls to an element who's ID matches the hash. So with the link you provided, the page scrolls directly to the anchor with an id of `antartica`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<a name="fragment_name" />` method of defining fragments has been deprecated in favor of using `id`s.  So when you go to http://dev.epicwebdesign.ca/karen/2-4/a/#antartica, the browser thinks you want to go to `<div id="antarctica"/>`, which is at the top of the page, instead of `<a name="antarctica" />`, which is at the bottom of the page.

Comment: We figured it out at the same time. Good to know, I hadn't heard of that before.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, in chrome at least, that it considers an ID an internal link, not just a name. The ID's of the images conflicted with the names of the headers. Once the ids were suffixed with "img" it works

Answer (score 0):

To add to cimmanon's answer (and in case your referenced page changes).

**Note:** Kindly paste your code for future reference.

---

Change your anchors at the top of the page from:

```
<div id="continents">
    <a href="#northamerica" id="northamerica"><img src="northamerica.png"></a>
    <a href="#southamerica" id="southamerica"><img src="southamerica.png"></a>
    <a href="#asia" id="asia"><img src="asia.png"></a>
    <a href="#europe" id="europe"><img src="europe.png"></a>
    <a href="#oceania" id="oceania"><img src="oceania.png"></a>
    <a href="#antartica" id="antartica"><img src="antartica.png"></a>
    <a href="#africa" id="africa"><img src="africa.png"></a>
</div>
```

to:

```
<div id="continents">
    <a href="#northamericaSection" id="northamerica"><img src="northamerica.png"></a>
    <a href="#southamericaSection" id="southamerica"><img src="southamerica.png"></a>
    <a href="#asiaSection" id="asia"><img src="asia.png"></a>
    <a href="#europeSection" id="europe"><img src="europe.png"></a>
    <a href="#oceaniaSection" id="oceania"><img src="oceania.png"></a>
    <a href="#antarticaSection" id="antartica"><img src="antartica.png"></a>
    <a href="#africaSection" id="africa"><img src="africa.png"></a>
</div>
```

Notice that I've changed the `href` on all links.

And change your heading below from:

```
<a id="antartica">
    <h1>Antartica</h1>
</a>
```

to:

```
<h1 id="antarticaSection">Antartica</h1>
```

Without the anchor (unless you plan on linking it to something else).